# How to resize disk partitions?

Tags: partitioning, disk

This is a link to my disk partition image.

[image]

I want to increase the size of my ext4 disk by around 20-30 GB. I want to use the free space in my `/dev/sda2` or `/dev/sda3` or `/dev/sda5` to increase my ext4 size. Please tell me how to do this in detail.

Comment: Posible duplicate :  http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions and

Comment: Your link is dead. Can you check your link again?

Comment: @edwinksl i checked the link it showing me the image

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. Your image is probably private, so nobody else can see it.

Comment: @edwinksl now check the link

Answer (score -1):

You can use gparted to move & resize your partitions. If you're going to be working on your root partition ie. "mounted at /" you'll need to make a livecd or bootable usb drive to boot into gparted.

More info can be found [in this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted).

Edit: Now that your image link is working, I can be a little more clear. If you were to shrink and move to the right your `sda5` partition that will add to the amount of unallocated space between `sda7` and `sda5`.

Being that you're going to be working on your root parition, you'll need to do it from a [gparted live usb](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php).

Once you've shrunk `sda5` to the right, you can drag the boundary of `sda7` to the right, using that unallocated space to make it bigger.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.