# Resize disk partitioning

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a question regarding disk partitions on a computer that I recently acquired from work:

This laptop only runs Ubuntu. I've contacted an admin at work and they don't know anything about this computer - apparently everything on it (apart from what I've added, of course) is exactly the way it was when it arrived from Lenovo, so the sizes and specifications of the partitions I describe below were what the laptop shipped with.

When I open the `Disks` app, I see three partitions:

- "EFI System Partition 1"
- "PQSERVICE Partition 2"
- "Filesystem Partition 3"
- And then "Free Space."

As you'll see in the screenshot I've linked to below, I've got oodles of free space that are going unused.
Based on the research I've done that I can understand, the partition that I want to expand is "Filesystem Partition 3" (which is 58 GB and has 39 GB free).

**Screenshot of disk space:**

[image: screenshot of disk space]

I saw, [in this article](https://www.ryadel.com/en/resize-extend-disk-partition-unallocated-disk-space-linux-centos-rhel-ubuntu-debian/), that expanding disk partitions is a common issue. But is the method outlined here the only or the best way to go about it? I have a few questions in regards to the process, especially since that article was written in 2017 and things may have changed since then:

- Is "Filesystem Partition 3" actually the partition that I want to expand? This seems to be the partition where all my documents and applications 'live' (I'm guessing this is what is meant by 'root') and, rather than that paltry 58 GB being eaten up, I'd like to be able to save documents, files, and applications to a bigger space.
- It seems that 'Disks' has an option to resize any given partition. I've clicked on that option for 'Filesystem Partition 3' and it seems like it will indeed resize the partition so that I can use much more of the 961 GB of free space. This looks like it can be accomplished in a straightforward way, by dragging sliders to adjust the size of the partition. But is this actually how I can/should resize the partition? Or should I be doing this in the Terminal, as the author of the article linked above outlines?
- If this is something I should be doing in Terminal, is the process outlined in that link advisable, or is there a better (or easier) way to do so?
- If I resize the partition, should I expect to lose everything? Obviously I will back up my files before resizing so I don't lose any data, but can I expect to lose Ubuntu itself as well?

The question on these boards that seems to most closely resemble mine is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792206/how-to-resize-disk-partitions), but the answer here suggests using something called `gparted`. This question was asked in 2016, so is this a function that `Disks` now performs, or would I still need to use `gparted`?

Comment: I normally use gparted from live installer. They have improved Disks, but I still do not use it. You cannot change mounted partitions, so have to use live installer. You can expand / (root) or create a new partition as /home for your data & user settings. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving  Separate /home makes it slightly easier to back up or do new install.  Some also just create data partition(s) for some data. Best not to have too many to manage.

Comment: Don’t follow the 2017 article. It’s about something called LVM which you don’t have set up so it’s not applicable. You need to run GParted in a live environment. The Ubuntu installer has a “Try Ubuntu” option which opens a live environment and has GParted available. If you search for how to create a Ubuntu installer key drive and create one you will find it easy to use GParted.

Comment: Keep things simple.  Your root partition is all you need, do not touch the other two, and have empty space where it is easiest to expand into.  If expecting only documents and a few downloads, then probably only need a few hundred GBs of free space.  If expecting to download many videos, will want all of free space.  Should only fill up an OS partition to about 80% full, will want to think about another drive to hold data/videos after that.

Comment: Thanks very much for this useful and patient explanation. I used gparted from the live installer and resize the /home partition without any fuss. Thank you again!